# python module not found error

Tags: python-3.x, pip, quandl

This question has been asked a few times, but the remedy appears to complicated enough that I'm still searching for a user specific solution.

I recently installed Quandl module using pip command. Even after successful installation my python idle is still showing

[image: error]

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "F:\Python36\Machine Learning\01.py", line 3, in <module>
    import Quandl
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'Quandl'
```

1. I have used import command in my code.
2. I am using python 3.6.1 version.
3. I am working on a windows 10 Desktop.
4. I have also tried re-installation of module.

[image: cmd image]

Comment: What comes up if you type `where python`?

Comment: Did you try: `pip3 install quandl`?

Comment: I think you are asking for where python command in cmd. So it gives `F:\Python36\python.exe`

Comment: Yes that's what I was asking, thanks.

Comment: I tried command `pip3 install quandl` just now but still no progress :(

Comment: thank you guys for your time and support, I just solved my problem by using  "quandl" instead of "Quandl" :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can better navigate to your python scripts folder and open a command window there and try `pip3 install quandl` .Hope this helps.

Comment: Correct me if I am wrong, you are asking me to navigate to python scripts folder on cmd window and try installing quandl again. I tried this just now but not working.  [image](http://imgur.com/a/apKj0)

Comment: ya go ahead try that

Comment: will you consider checking in the case-sensitivity for e.g. try quandl instead of Quandl

Comment: your welcome. can you accept my answer and upvote it.